SQL Job Manual Run vs Scheduled RUN
I am having a situation with the scheduled job running longer when it runs on scheduled time, but runs absolutely fine when executing manually.
The job is basically for creating the csv file using SSIS and I am using SSIS catalog to execute the package

I ran the job manually and it took 10 min to finish and when scheduled it takes almost 75 min


I would suggest you consult the SSISDB logs and see what's going on there; your instance is a "black box" to us, so we have no idea what it's doing.

Not to mention, there could be a wealth of reasons. Perhaps there was another overnight process running at the same time that was blocking access to a some data for 60+ minutes. Maybe the server was very quiet at 10:36. Perhaps the extracts are different and the data for the latter is significantly smaller. Maybe the location you save the file to was suffering storage issues and write speeds were significantly effected. Maybe the speed fairy visiting you at ~10:30 and so your attempt was magically fast. There are many reasons, and we don't know which.

If this is a consistent problem, look into it, but if it's a one off I wouldn't read too much into it.

Thank you Thom. Its consistent problem and always same number of records are being exported. I will may be do some more research. Thank you for looking into this

Perhaps there's something else running at 5 am which slow things down. The actual execution isn't performed by  even when you trigger the job, so there shouldn't be any difference due to that

"Its consistent problem" Then I would look into what step is the slow part in the process, and then work out what could be affected that.

Could this be a security issue? Scheduled running under the agent credentials, while manual running under the user credentials.

Sql agent doesnt use the starting user but queues the job and runs it under its own context

I would hazard a guess that a DB maintenance "task" is running at night/early morning. Re-indexing causes table locking and loads up storage a lot.
